# Searching a particular index using Sphinx, from multiple indexes, through PHP script

Tags: php, search, indexing, sphinx

I have multiple sources, like this (say)

```
source src1{
...
}
source src2{
...
}
```

AND
    index src1{
    ...
    }
    index src2{
    ...
    }

src1 has sql query from one individual table and src2 has sql query based on another individual table.

Now, in the PHP script, how do I specify, which indexer to use?
Normally, in the PHP script, we write it this way

```
$ss = new SphinxClient;
$ss->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$ss->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
```

Since, there is no mention about the indexer being used. It's useless to search both indexes (i.e., both tables). I want to search the index src2(say) i.e., data from the second table. So, how do I specify this in my php script, that sphinx should search only that particular indexer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Query call includes the index(s) to search

```
$res = $cl->Query($query,"src1");
```

Comment: that seems a recurrent question :-)

Answer (score 1):

For one index (per Barry Hunter)

```
$res = $cl->Query($query,"src1");
```

or

For multiple indexes for one query.

```
$res = $cl->Query($query,"src1 src2 src3 src4");
```